# como puedo autoacompletar un input que se añade el html despues de que selecciono una opcion?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, autocomplete

Tengo una serie de `input` tipo radio, donde selecciono que tipo de itinerario se va a mostrar:

```
<div class=" row col  m12 l12 mt-1 right">
 <label>
    <input type="radio" name="intinerary[0][intinerary_type_id]" class="intinerary_type_id" value="1" title="Elija el tipo de vuelo" required>
    <span> Vuelo</span>
 </label>
 <label>
    <input type="radio" name="intinerary[0][intinerary_type_id]" class="intinerary_type_id" value="2" title="Elija el tipo de vuelo" required>
    <span>Hotel</span>
 </label>
 <label>
     <input type="radio" name="intinerary[0][intinerary_type_id]" class="intinerary_type_id" value="3" title="Elija el tipo de vuelo" required>
<span>Vuelo y Hotel</span>
 </label>
```

```
<div class="row flights ml-5 mr-5 mt-2">
```

Se manda a llamar el siguiente código con `jquery`:

```
$(".flightType").change(function() {
            if ($inputFlight = $(this).val() == 1) { // ida 

    $('.flights').html(
 '<div class="row mt-4">
         <h5>Vuelo</h5>
      <div class="input-field col l2 m2 s6">
         <label for="airline">Línea Aérea:</label>
         <input type="text" name="flight_departures[0][airline]" class="validate autocomplete" id="airline" required>
     </div>
     <div class="input-field col l3 m3 s6">
         <label for="from">Origen:</label>
         <input type="text" name="flight_departures[0][from]" class="validate" required>
     </div>
         <div class="input-field col l3 m3 s6">
         <label for="to">Destino:</label>
         <input type="text" name="flight_departures[0][to]" class="validate" required>
     </div>
     <div class=" col l2 m2 s6" >
         <label for="date">Fecha: </label>
         <input type="date" class="datepicker" name="flight_departures[0][date]" placeholder="Fecha:" required>
     </div>
     <div class="col l2 m2 s6"><label for="time">Hora: </label>
         <input type="time" class="timepicker" name="flight_departures[0][time]"  required>
     </div>
 </div>'

     ).change();
```

Y quiero llamar la función de `autocomplete` de `jqueryUI` para auto completar con las lineas aéreas en el `input` con el `id= airline`.

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
  data: {
    "LR" : "(LACSA) LINEAS AEREAS COSTARRICENSES, S.A. -> LR",
    "ACN" : "AEREO CALAFIA SA DE CV -> ACN",
    "ASG" : "AEREOSERVICIO GUERRERO SA DE CV -> ASG",
    "AR" : "AEROLINEAS ARGENTINAS -> AR",
    "VW" : "AEROMAR -> VW",
    "AA" : "AMERICAN AIR LINES, INC -> AA",
    "AMEX" : "AMERICAN EXPRESS -> AMEX",
    "HP" : "AMERICAN WEST AIRLINES -> HP"
  },
});
```

No se si es porque esta oculto y hasta que le doy click aparece en el contenido del `html`.